# UICollectionViewCell content not resizing to layout.itemSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass that I have defined in a nib...

[image]

It uses AutoLayout to layout all of the (two, lol) components. The date picker is laid out with left, right and bottom constraints to the superview and a height constraint to make sure it always shows full content.

Then, when configuring the layout of the collection view I use this...

```
_layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
_layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.frame));
_layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
_layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
```

This works as when I'm debugging the view I can see that the frame of the `UICollectionViewCell` is correct, but the content of the cell is not resizing as you can see from these two screenshots.

**Collection View Cell selected and is correct.**
[image: Collection View Cell selected and is correct.]

**Content of collection view selected and is not correct.**
[image: Content of collection view selected and is not correct.]

In fact, you can see that the content is the same size and shape as defined in the nib. But 
this should resize to match the cell size. If I make the nib content really small it stays really small in the app.

This is, potentially, happening in `UITableViewCells` too as the cell separators are not showing all the way across the screen for bigger devices.

Comment: I've managed to get around this for now by adding `self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;` in the `layoutSubviews` method. But I shouldn't need this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're showing in your two images. In the top image what is the blue, and what's the gray? And what is that a picture of, a storyboard, or another xib? It looks like you have a bunch of views, a collection view, and a CCClock cell there. Your overall structure isn't clear.

Comment: @rdelmar the first image is a nib of the collection view cell subclass. The second two images are the view debugger in Xcode 6 and I have limited the view (with the sliders) to only show what I'm interested in. The blue is the selected view and the bread crumb trail shows the view's superview trail back to `UIWindow`. I was trying to show that the cell's frame (2nd picture) is correct and the cell's contentView (3rd picture) is not resizing properly to match the frame. The view debugger is really helpful if you haven't used it before.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem using a xib cell similar to yours, and registering that with a code created collection view. Did you make the collection view in a xib or storyboard? Can you add an explanation of your view hierarchy? Also, what are the 1's in the blue ovals next to the image view in your first image?

Comment: @rdelmar the 1s are an aspect ratio constraint. Let me make a minimum failing project and stick it on github.

Comment: @rdelmar well, I tried but I can't duplicate it. The cell is defined in a xib. The collection view is created in a storyboard. I've fixed it for now with my first comment but it may be due to the fact it's more than just one layout and swapping out delegates and datasources. Anyway. I've got round it for now :)