# Why won't my UIImageView stretch after upgrading to ios-sdk8?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation, nslayoutconstraint

We're currently in the process of upgrading our app to build with the iOS8 SDK, and we've run into problems with `UIImageViews` in `UICollectionViews`.

The problem arises only when running the app on a device running ios7, it works as expected on ios8. BUilding the same code on SDK 7 yields the correct results for ios7. The content view of the cell resized as expected on rotation, but the image does not follow. The content mode of the image is set as follows:

```
cell.image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

The `UIImageView` is tied to the content view of the `UICollectionViewCell` with 4 constraints; *leading, trailing, top* and *bottom* space are all set to 0.

It is almost as if the leading and trailing constraints are not being respected, but we get no warnings at runtime. The green square in the image below represents our image view. The blue represents the collection view cell that can be seen peeking out under the image view in landscape mode.

[image: the image does not stretch with the content view in landscape mode]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug I think. I had the same problem [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019122/uicollectionviewcell-content-not-resizing-to-layout-itemsize)

My fix was to put `self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;` into the `layoutSubviews` method of the cell.

i.e. it is not the image view that is not resizing correctly but it is the `cell.contentView` not resizing correctly.

Comment: @MiaClarke Have you tried it? I thought the content was resizing in mine too.

Comment: @MiaClarke Glad you got it sorted. Happy to help.